# in python , i have index but i need to get the index of an element in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

DataFrame df

```
    Buy Sell
0   5.0  NaN
1   NaN  10.0
2   NaN  NaN
3   5.0  NaN
4   NaN  10.0
5   18.0 NaN
6   NaN  30.0
```

#i need get the index value by providing the cell reference (i.e, df['Buy'][i])

```
Buy_index=df['Buy'].values.tolist().index(df['Buy'][0])
Sell_index=df['Sell'].values.tolist().index(df['Sell'][4])
print(Buy_index)
print(Sell_index)
```

Actual Result:

```
0
1
```

Expected Result:

```
0
4
```

Help me

Comment: You already have the indices `0` and `4` in your code, so why do you need to look those up anywhere? I don't think the code example you listed fully describes the problem you intend to solve. Can you add more detail about where the values `0` and `4` come from?